# Is there a trick to breaking barrels?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I am trying to finish the trial at the Colosseum, where you have to break barrels within a time limit.

I managed to squeak through the first round, but the second one is giving me a lot of trouble.

Is there a pattern I should follow, or an order to break them in, or anything else in particular (besides speed and accuracy) that will help me finish off all the barrels in the second round?

Comment: I assume very few people are playing this game these days (I just beat it over the weekend) but I found that the best way to beat that challenge was to throw barrels. It'll destroy both the barrel you're throwing and any ones it hits. It also helps prepare you for the fight against Hercules later on, so I think that's what they were going for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really any strategy specifically to it. Just got to beat the barrels. [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6t-QsRlNAA#?t=7m00s) recommends that you do the outside barrels first on the second one to make things easier time-wise.

Comment: Argh. I was scared that might be the answer. *braces herself for the bajillionth try*

Comment: Doing the outside ones first definitely helps!

Comment: I don't remember how, but there's a certain move that allows Sora to actually hit one barrel into another, breaking both. I think it's an ability you have to level up to unlock.

Comment: @Tristan It's the finishing strike to your combo. You last attack sends the barrel flying and breaks other barrels

Comment: I'm only familiar with KH2, but in that game it's actually possible to vary the length of your combo by equipping abilities that increase/decrease the number of attacks in your combo. If that's true in 1 as well, then shortening your combo to get more finishers would help a great deal.